# Google Tango - Markers .xml not saved

Tags: unity-game-engine, area, google-project-tango, tango

I am currently working with a Lenovo Phab 2 Pro - Google Tango. I installed the new Gankino SDK. 
After using area learning I would like to retrieve the coordinates of the markers places during the area learning.
When I go into the folder at the following address: `LenovoPhab2Pro\Memory\Android\Data` : I can not find the corresponding file like: `com.CompanyName.ProductName`.

What I want to do in the end is to make an area learning on a piece and place some markers and then retrieve the position of the markers in the `.xml` and finally place virtual objects at the positions of these markers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I solved it!
I directly have access to this file in the phone. I copied and pasted this .XML file in the download folder to be able to acces it when the phone is plugged to my computer.